# WIndows 7 User folder

Tags: windows-7

I am migrating someone with a windows 7 32 bit laptop and an Xp desktop to windows 7 64-bit on both machines. Both machines are 64 bit capable. I am going to back up all data but want to make some things easier for me. Can I copy his user profile folder from the windows 7 laptop to the new 64 bit installation without encountering permissions issues?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably can, but I have found after migrating several computers now that it's just easier to use the [Windows Easy Transfer](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/products/features/windows-easy-transfer) tool that Microsoft has available.  It's a bit slow, but I haven't yet had a problem with a file or setting not being transferred.